# How to move paid app to free app and retain purchase for existing users

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a paid app on the app store since 2010, and now I want to move to a free/in-app-purchase model. However, I am not adding functionality, but rather make part of the functionality available via in-app-purchase. Now since I have thousands of users already which have paid for the app, I don't want them to pay again for the in-app-purchase.

So my questions would be:

1. Is it possible to identify in-code whether or not the user has already purchased the earlier non-free version of the app?
2. If this was not possible, is there a way to manually grant in-app-purchase items to individuals, so they can just mail me and I can unlock it for them?

I know that I can store user defaults and the like, however I suspect this will be rather error prone, since people might have new devices, several devices, not have updated for years and all that. Therefore, my preferred solution would be 1), since it should just always work out well I guess.

Comment: Verify the receipt of the user on your server's backend and then grant them access to the features: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store

Comment: I don't have no backend server. Its a standalone/offline app.

Comment: Then it's probably not possible.

Comment: Apple does not recommend that you verify the receipt on the client side, but that does not mean that it is not possible.

Comment: Ok what a pity. So theres no way to switch to free app? Other than remembering in user defaults on the device itself?

Is it at least possible to manually grant the purchase?

Comment: @user826955 i had done that by using user defaults. There is no other way and Apple will reject your application for manual access because the feature for which user is paying should be automatically enabled after payment.